# how to call controller/action from button click in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple login screen. On click of button i want to call LoginUser action defined in Home controller. I am getting HTTP 404, resource not found error. The address bar after clicking the button shows "http://localhost:13805/Home/LoginUser". I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. Really appreciate any help on this.

Here is the button:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("LoginUser", "Home")'" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

and here is the action defined in Home controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginUser(string username, string password)
    {
        bool loginSuccess = false;
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            AuthenticationMode = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthenticationMode"];
            if (AuthenticationMode.Equals("Forms"))
            {
                int userId = CheckUserLogin(username);
                if (userId > 0)
                {
                    CurrentUserId = userId;
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
                    LoadMenu();
                    loginSuccess = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    loginSuccess = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                loginSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            loginSuccess = true;
        }

        if (loginSuccess)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "home");
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a `onclick()` event making a call to a GET method, attached to a submit button making a call to a POST method? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your submit button should not have an onclick action.

It should submit a Form whose action is your endpoint ("LoginUser", "Home"), which you've correctly setup to accept HttpPost

You need a form something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){

<!-- form here -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked fine. I am currently using _layout.cshtml file and my form is declared in there. Can I have 2 forms in the same view? How would we handle 2 buttons linked to 2 different controller/actions within one form?

Comment: @user2615296 if I were putting two buttons with two different actions into one form I'd add javascript click events to the buttons and let javascript do the serialization and POSTing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can change your button type from "submit" to "button" then your code should work as it is.

Below is my working code example